# Breadth First Combination

Tags: c++, combinations, breadth-first-search

What is the most efficient way to find all of the breadth-first combinations of a given set?

E.g:
Given set of elements {1,2,4}, the output should be as follows (and in this order as well - not necessarily the numerical values, but the element values - first should output layer 1 (one element), then layer 2 (two elements), and lastly layer 3 (three elements)):

`1
2
4
1 2
1 4
2 4
1 2 4`

Comment: Use a binary counter. Each element corresponds to a bit.

Comment: Doesn't that output it like this? (Not per layer)
```{1}
{2}
{1,2}
{4} 
{1,4}
{2,4}
{1,2,4}```

Comment: Sure does.  But can you think of a way to store each subset by its size?Then print afterwards?https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::set<int>> enumerate_all_subsets(const vector <int> &nums) {
    std::vector<std::set<int>> result;
    for(auto i = 0ull; i < (1 << nums.size()); ++ i) {
        std::set<int> elements;
        for(auto k = 0; k < nums.size(); ++ k)
            if((i >> k) & 1)
                elements.insert(nums[k]);
        result.push_back(elements);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This iterates over a vector of a size up to size 63 (if your unsigned long longs are 64 bit). Any larger vectors should probably be rethought as that would take a while as this is `O(2^n)`.

Basically each bit of the `unsigned long long i` represents a position in `nums` and if it should be added to the set or not.

Comment: I implemented something similar to that, is there any way to get rid of the fact that you have to create objects to intermediately store the elements? (like how MFisherKDX said)

Comment: The best way would be to make the temporary storage what you use later with a `result.push_back(std::move(elements));` and not have to copy your data over if you are concerned about copy performance of the sets (not sure how large amounts of data we are talking here). You could also use `result.back()` as a temporary set where you add things.

Comment: `std::vector<std::set<int>> result(1 << nums.size())` and `std::set<int> elements& = result[i];` and get rid of the `push_back`

Comment: You forget to sort the result by Length to have expected output. Else it is the wrong order: [Demo](https://ideone.com/Pi1yfL).

Answer (score 0):

You might use `std::next_permutation`:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void BreadthFirstCombination(const std::vector<T>& v, F f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != v.size() + 1; ++i) {
        std::vector<bool> mask(i, true);
        mask.resize(v.size(), false);
        do {
            f(v, mask);
        } while (std::prev_permutation(mask.begin(), mask.end()));
    }
}
```

With usage similar too:

```
auto printer = [](const auto&v, const std::vector<bool>& mask)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        if (mask[i]) {
            std::cout << v[i] << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;    
};
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 4};
BreadthFirstCombination(v, printer);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/J5uW39)

So doing permutations of

- false false false
- true false false (-> 100 010 001)
- true true false (-> 110 101 011)
- true true true

If you want to keep empty set, begin the loop with `i = 1`